# dataSource flag in typeorm cli

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I'm starting a project with typeorm. My configuration file looks like this:

> ormconfig.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();


const {
    DATABASE_HOST,
    DATABASE_PORT,
    DATABASE_NAME,
    DATABASE_PASSWORD
} = process.env




export default {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: DATABASE_HOST,
    port: DATABASE_PORT,
    database: DATABASE_NAME,
    password: DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    entities: [
        "./api/modules/documents/entity/*.js",
    ],
    migrations: [
        "./api/database/migrations/*.js",
    ],
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: "./api/database/migrations",
        entitiesDir: "api/database/modules/**/entity"
    }
}
```

> package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "gulp": "node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js",
    "start": "nodemon ./src/app.js",
    "start:api": "nodemon ./api/server.js",
    "typeorm": "node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./ormconfig.js"
},
```

When i try to run the command `yarn typeorm migration:run` its show this message:

```
Runs all pending migrations.

Opções:
  -h, --help         Exibe ajuda                                      [booleano]
  -d, --dataSource   Path to the file where your DataSource instance is defined.
                                                                   [obrigatório]
  -t, --transaction  Indicates if transaction should be used or not for
                     migration run. Enabled by default.      [padrão: "default"]
  -v, --version      Exibe a versão                                   [booleano]

Missing required argument: dataSource
```

What would be `datasource` flag?
I tried with typeorm cli installed globally, same problem happens

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using typeorm 0.3.x in your project while you are following  0.2.x configurations. Check your installed version on your `package.json`.

If you are using 0.3.x and want to keep with the current version you should follow the documentation: https://typeorm.io/data-source

Otherwise you can just downgrade your version executing:

```
npm install typeorm@0.2.45
```